# Apache 2.4 not working with php-fpm 5.2

Tags: php, apache2.4

I have an Apache 2.4.X server configured to perform a `ProxyPassMatch` to php-fpm 5.2 daemon:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://localhost:1201/home/sites_web/client/toto.com/www retry=0 timeout=300
```

The fpm daemon is listening:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1201              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      28315/php-cgi
```

However am getting HTTP404 when accessing php files if phpfpm5.2 is used. if php 5.5 is used am able to access the php.files.

In fpm logs am getting the following output:

> Apr 17 12:05:55.551566 [NOTICE] fpm_unix_init_main(), line 284:
>   getrlimit(nofile): max:4096, cur:1024 Apr 17 12:05:55.551655 [NOTICE]
>   fpm_event_init_main(), line 88: libevent: using epoll Apr 17
>   12:05:55.553725 [NOTICE] fpm_init(), line 52: fpm is running, pid
>   17076
>
> Apr 17 12:05:55.556172 [NOTICE] fpm_children_make(), line 352: child
>   17079 (pool toto) started Apr 17 12:05:55.556642 [NOTICE]
>   fpm_children_make(), line 352: child 17081 (pool toto) started Apr 17
>   12:05:55.556890 [NOTICE] fpm_children_make(), line 352: child 17082
>   (pool toto) started Apr 17 12:05:55.557123 [NOTICE]
>   fpm_children_make(), line 352: child 17083 (pool toto) started Apr 17
>   12:05:55.557138 [NOTICE] fpm_event_loop(), line 107: libevent:
>   entering main loop

Is there specific configuration to put on the Vhost?

Comment: Did you follow this thread https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?3,4539 ?

Comment: Yes but there are no error in my logs. Just notice.